# parsing string messages in c++

Tags: c++

I'm asking for a suggestion regarding the parsing of text messages. I have a list of messages in text format, in the format:

```
dev1.comm1 param

dev1.comm2 param

dev1.comm11 param

dev2.comm1 param

dev3.comm1 param
```

I need to parse each received line of text and find out the message contained. I did a parser for binary messages with lookup tables, i.e.:

```
first byte table = 
{

0x01 -> table 0x01,

0x02 -> table 0x01,

0x03 -> message 0x03

}
```

where `0x01` and `0x02` are the start of messages with length greater than 1, while `0x03` is a message made up of only one byte. If the first byte of the received message is `0x01` I go on comparing the second byte with the content of the table `0x01`, while if the first byte is `0x03` I return the id of the message `0x03` and get it in some other function. Obviously I implemented this with structures and pointers, this is just some form of pseudocode.

I would like to have a similar solution for text messages, but the one I outlined above seems not that good to me, also because I have long text messages, and I would end up with too many tables.
Is there a cleaner solution, in the case of text messages? A parse tree perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

A parse tree of course.

Perhaps you need to write a FSM for long sentences.

Comment: With FSM you mean a state machine? So I would read each char and then go in a wait_for_something state each time?

Comment: Yes a state machine. You can make up rules like state machine to parse a long sentence. I think it may short your table's length.

Comment: A parser? For such a symple syntax? It's a bit overkill. A simple FSM would work equally well. State "DEV" : read characters & append to devname, until `.` which transitions to state "COMM": read characters & append to commanme, until whitespace : skip and transition to state "PARAM" etc.

Comment: ok, but the commands are something like one hundred, not only the ones i shown above, that's why in the similar case of binary data i used tables and a loop.

Comment: maybe a map could help with matching strings to commands, whatever a command really looks like in your implementation. might as well be a function pointer.